# Format R Markdown output so that it can be copied and pasted to twitter

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra, flextable

Trying to do daily reports with Rmarkdown on covid-19 data. Want to tweet top 10 values from tables, but the options tried so far leave no spaces - tabs are erased when the tweet button is pushed. Have tried {kableExtra} with html output and {flextable} with word output, but when copied and pasted, the column separations are 'disappearing' tabs.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to obtain a table with spaces or commas between columns?

Example Rmarkdown script is [here](https://github.com/markhogue/US_per_mil_pop_covid-19/blob/master/covid-us-per-million-jhu.Rmd), if interested, but the question is meant to be general and not require looking at the script.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a picture of the table (which looks quite good then).

You could do this like this:

```
library("knitr")
library(kableExtra")
knitr::kable(mtcars, "latex") %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = "striped") %>%
  kableExtra::save_kable("test.png")
```

Or does this have any downsides you don't want?

**Addition:**
Alright, I didn't look at your file - seems you want to add 4 tables but not copy 4 images.

Short question here - isn't this then quite hard with the 280 char limit of twitter...?

But what you could do is the following:

````
```{r, echo = F}

aa <- knitr::kable(head(mtcars[, 1:4]), "pipe")
for (i in 1:length(aa)) {
   aa[i] <- gsub(" ", ",", aa[i])
   aa[i] <- paste(aa[i], "\n")
}
aa
```
````

In your code chunk save the table to a variable. This will then just be a table in markdown format. Now you can parse through and replace and alter chars how you need it.

Comment: Thanks, Steffen. The downsides are having to make my latex installation work, which might be possible, but then opening four different png's. I feel safer copying and pasting from one report if a way can be found.

Comment: The tweets are under the character limit after removing extra spaces and being careful with intro discussion. If it gets tight, I abbreviate the state names. I've been manually replacing tabs with spaces. If I use any of the formats in kable including the pipe format you suggest, tabs are provided. The only exception is the rst format, which also removes line breaks.

Comment: Oh, I think you didn't get what I meant. Take a look at the code in the answer now. I thought of editing the table via R code to your likes. Try this, maybe it helps :) Of course you could alter it like you exactly need it (mine is just an example)

Comment: Thanks again Steffen. You helped me figure out an answer. I'm going with: `case_report <- case_report %>% 
  select(c(st, cases, cases_1M_pop)) %>% 
  mutate(st = paste0(st, " ")) %>% 
  mutate(cases = paste0(as.character(cases), " ")) %>%
  mutate(cases_1M_pop = format(cases_1M_pop, digits = 2))`